# Join table or 2 Select queries?

Tags: php, loops, mysqli, while-loop

I have 2 relationship tables in my database.

I have been trying to get my head round the below.

I have contact table, and i have an order table.

I want to try and display the contact info (name, email etc) once, and then display the order information.

I know I can do that with:

```
<?php 
  $query = $db->prepare("SELECT *
                     FROM contact 
             WHERE type = ? 
             ORDER BY date") 
             or die(mysqli_error($db));  
  $type = "order";
  $query->bind_param('s', $type);
  $query->execute(); 
  $query->store_result(); 
  $query->bind_result($id, $name, $email, $date); 

  while ($query->fetch()) {
     $date = strtotime($date); 
     $date = date("F jS  Y", $date);
?>


From: <?php echo $name ?>

<input type="Checkbox" name="checkbox[]"  id="checkbox[]"value="<? echo $contactid; ?>">

<p>
<?php 
   echo $comments 
?>
</p>

<?php 
     echo $date ;
?>

<?php
     $order = $db->prepare("SELECT title, number
             FROM preorder 
             WHERE id = ? ") 
             or die(mysqli_error($db));  

     $order->bind_param('s', $id);
     $order->execute(); 
     $order->store_result(); 
     $order->bind_result( $title, $number ); 

     while ($order->fetch()) {
        echo $title, $number ; 
     }  
   } 
?>
```

That works fine, but feels wrong, and easier way to do it without doing 2 selects. I want to then display the orders, within that loop, so the name, email, etc is not repeated with each order.

Comment: Are you meaning display them in the order that they are saved or a user defined order?

Comment: This is what I have working at the moment i have edited the above, but feels a better way to do it with join table, but when i do join, it will list the the name each time there is an order. so it would display for example. bob order 3 screws, bob order 4 hammers, bob order 5 saws, want i am trying to do is instead have bob order 3 screws, 4 hammers, 5 saws. Can not post the code

Comment: why not add the display or display_order column to the contacts table and order by that column? If your not using a display id sort des so they appear from first to last? Confused, thats the same order you have there in your example.

Comment: was having problems posting the code, but it has been updated now

Comment: You could just order by contact_id and then just print "bob" if contact_id changed. If contact_id didn't change just print the items. More information about the tables would be useful.

Comment: show me the table your using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would solve it with a `left join` like this:

```
<?php
  $query = $db->prepare(
    "SELECT *, preorder.title, preorder.number " .
    "FROM contact " .
    "LEFT JOIN preorder  ON (contact.contactid = preorder.contactid) " .
    "WHERE type = ? ORDER BY contactid, date")
  or die(mysqli_error($db));
  $type = "order";
  $query->bind_param('s', $type);
  $query->execute();
  $query->store_result();
  $query->bind_result($id, $name, $email, $date, $title, $number);

  $last_id = false;
  while ($query->fetch()) {
    $date = strtotime($date);
    $date = date("F jS  Y", $date);

    if ($contactid != $last_id) {
?>
        From: <?php echo $name ?>
        <input type="Checkbox" name="checkbox[]" 
               id="checkbox[]" value="<? echo $contactid; ?>"> 
        <p>
            <?php
            echo $comments
            ?>
        </p>
<?php
      echo $date;
    }
    echo $title, $number;
    $last_id = $contactid;
  }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you,, that worked :), i was thinking instead of using foreach (still yet to use foreach) , but this is quick and nice :) Surely this is a common mysqli query that is used a lot?

Comment: I'm glad that my answer is useful for you (: . I'm not sure if this is common way to solve these kind of problems but that's the way I solve them and it worked out so far. @user3472437